# Arabic show Ù…Ø±ÙŠÙ in mysql using php and VS Code

Tags: php, mysql, visual-studio-code, utf-8, xampp

when I insert data to mysql, Arabic show Ù…Ø±ÙŠÙ in mysql, I'm using php and VS Code to write code

Collation in mysql is : utf8_general_ci in all column
encoding in VS Code is utf8

when I use echo"  ";
Arabic is show, and it is show when I insert data from XAMPP localhost, but when I insert data from php isn't show

I begginer with php

Comment: Please show the code that you use to connect to MySQL with PHP. You have to define the proper character encoding there, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: See Mojibake in [_utf8_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)